# Does Omniture support providing APIs?

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

Can someone help me out with this information if SiteCatalyst offers any API method which user can use to access data from its database (from the data which SiteCatalyst has collected from web).

We have option of scheduling reports but what if number of users is in some tens of thousands ? We cannot schedule reports for everyone. Hence this question came in my mind, if SiteCatalyst offers any API to facilitate this, which user can use and fetch data depending upon their need.

Thanks,
Adi

Comment: https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/index.php  Analytics API 1.4 is the one you want

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the reporting API as outlined here: https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/documentation/analytics-reporting-1-4/whatsnew

There aren't any API's that let you interact with the scheduled reports interface yet, so hopefully the reporting API gives you what you're looking for.